# Testing Forms in Play 2 with Java and JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework

So, testing in Play is causing me a headache and I'm hoping someone out there will have an answer to my problem.

I need to test my registration system (among many other things), which of course involves the submission of a form on behalf of the user.

My Stripped Down Version of Controller Action - add()

```
public static Result add() {

    String email = form().bindFromRequest().get("email");
    String name = form().bindFromRequest().get("name");
    String password = form().bindFromRequest().get("password");
    String password_confirm = form().bindFromRequest().get("password-confirm");

    [stripped out code]

    if(!check){
        flash("error", "Not a valid email, please use the email address provided by your employer");
            return redirect(
                routes.UserController.registration()
        );
    }
    else {
        String passwordHash = BCrypt.hashpw(form().bindFromRequest().get("password"), BCrypt.gensalt());

        // Create unverified User
        User newUser = User.create(
            form().bindFromRequest().get("email"),
            form().bindFromRequest().get("name"),
            passwordHash
        );
        // Generate verification key
        String key = newUser.verification_key;
        // Send verification email
        sendVerificationLink(key);

        flash("success", "Thanks for registering! We have sent you an email with a verification link.");
        return redirect(
            routes.Application.login()
        );
    }
```

Here's the JUnit Test I've written.

```
@Test
public void registerTest() {
    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String registeredUserName = "bob";
            String registeredUserEmail = "bob@gmail.ac.uk";
            String registeredUserPass = "secret";
            String registeredUserPassConfirm = "secret";

            Map<String, String> userData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            userData.put("name", registeredUserName);
            userData.put("email", registeredUserEmail);
            userData.put("password", registeredUserPass);
            userData.put("passwordconfirm", registeredUserPassConfirm);

            Result r = callAction(routes.ref.UserController.add(), fakeRequest()
                    .withFormUrlEncodedBody(Form.form(User.class).bind(userData).data()));       

            assertEquals(r, 200);
        }
    });
}
```

Given suitably correct details within the HashMap, r, in my mind, should return OK or 200?

However, I am getting the following... "expected: play.test.Helpers$1@29cd761a but was:<200>"

What is this "play.test.Helpers$1@29cd761a"? It looks like it referencing an object or memory address but I don't know why??

If this is vague in anyway, please just say so and I'll try to elaborate.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yo!

Sussed it!

For anyone else having a momentary brain fart... use the status() method to read the returned result!

```
Result r = callAction(routes.ref.UserController.add(), fakeRequest()
           .withFormUrlEncodedBody(Form.form(User.class).bind(userData).data()));  

assertEquals(200, status(r));
```